# 9 patch not working well

Tags: android, nine-patch

I have created a simple 9 patch for an android EditText background.
It works exactly as expected when I preview the graphical layout in eclipse.

The problem is that when I install the app on the device, the said EditText is horribly scaled, almost indistinguishable.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you post the 9-patch image and the screenshot from the device where it is installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably has garbage (pixels not exactly black) on the 9-patch area (1 pixel border) and hence it doesn't understand it as a 9-patch.

Save this image with the `draw9patch` tool and clean your project before building it!

Answer (score 3):

Few things I can think about:

1. Is it called image_name.9.png?
2. Did you save it using the draw9patch tool?
3. Did you place the image in all draw folders? (hdpi, mdpi, etc.)

You state that it works well in Eclipse, so it probably isn't 1 or 2.

Comment: I have not placed it in all draw folders.
I thought that once it is a @drawable, it can be accessed by the app, regardless of the device.

Comment: You should work with different drawable folders anyway. Just try it out and see if it works :)

Comment: It is true that the images can be accessed from the "drawable" folder on all devices, but it might result in unwanted scaling. Generally you never want actual image files in the "drawable" folder. XML files in the "drawable" folder is no problem, though.

Comment: It didn't. Afterwards, I retried with a different 9 patch and worked. 
Perhaps there were some pixels that were not 100% transparent.
Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Pewiity my 9patch was called left_2.9.png. it was showing well in layout design but when i install in my device, everything does a mess.  it was even working well before in my device but suddenly it stopped. i changed the file name to left.9.png but still with no success. this is in android studio 2.2 preview 3